# How to take a string as signal to convert a previous string?

Tags: browser, hyperlink, autohotkey

How to type `WORD vv` anywhere, and get the browser to open a link containing `WORD` in it? I know the script must have

```
Run, browserpath www.example.com/x/y/z/WORD.html
```

but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
:*:vv::
InputBox, UserInput, WORD, Enter a WORD, , 200, 120
if not ErrorLevel
{
    ; remove first and last white spaces
    UserInput := trim(UserInput)
    ; replace all middle white spaces with +
    UserInput := StrReplace(UserInput, A_Space , "+", UserInput)
    Run, "browserpath" "www.example.com/x/y/z/%UserInput%.html"     
}
return
```

**Examples:**

```
; google with the default browser    
Run, https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%UserInput%

; google images with IE    
Run, iexplore.exe "https://images.google.com/images?hl=en&@@"

; google autohotkey with another browser    
Run, "browserpath" "https://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=ahkscript.org&q=%UserInput%"

; autohotkey.com
https://www.autohotkey.com/search/search.php?query_string=%UserInput%

; autohotkey manual    
https://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=ahkscript.org&q=%UserInput%

; wikipedia    
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=%UserInput%&go=Go
```

Comment: nice idea. Thanks. Do you have any tips for me to try? :)

Comment: Do you know how to remove first and last white spaces in the input, and replace all middle white spaces with `+`?